# Getting formatted date in date format rather than String

Tags: java, date

I'm running the program written below, but instead of printing in mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm  format it prints in the normal date format(ie. Day Date and time)

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
Date date = sdf.parse(sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime()));
```

The reason i'm doing this is because the existing method accepts parameters in Date format, so i need to send the above mentioned date object to it.

Please point out the mistake or suggest some other alternative.
Thanks

Comment: I don't understand. You are formatting the `Date` from a `Calendar` and then parsing it back to a `Date`. Why not `Date date = Calendar.getInstance().getTime()`?

Answer (score 7):

Date objects don't have a format. The Date class is a wrapper around a single long, the number of milliseconds since the epoch. You can't "format" a Date, only a String. Pass around a Date/Calendar internally, and format it whenever you need to display it, log it, or otherwise return it to the user.

Comment: To expand a bit… You cannot format a date-time object (`java.util.Date` in this case), but you can generate a String representation of that date-time info. Do so by using a formatter. For j.u.Date & .Calendar that means `SimpleDateFormat` class. But java.util.Date & .Calendar are notoriously troublesome; avoid them. Instead use either [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or the new java.time package in Java 8. With Joda-Time, use a [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object obtained through DateTimeFormat factories.

Answer (score 1):

Change the format to MM/dd/yyyy. Month is denoted by capital M.

Check below URL for valid formats

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: I'm not downvoting because you did find a bug in his code, but I don't think this addresses his question at all.

Comment: I just answered his question. You are right that date or calendar object does not have any standard format in itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your formatter works quite fine (apart from the mm vs. MM bug). You get a formatted string from the date and then create a copy from your date by parsing the formatted string:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm");
Date now = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();
String formattedNow = sdf.format(now); // == "09/24/2013 01:59"
Date now2 = sdf.parse(formattedNow); // == now
```

Comment: It is still not solving the problem.. :(

Comment: Then please specify the problem in more details, because I don't know what your problem actually is. What's the "existing method" for example and when/how does the date get printed in the wrong format?